# How much does file write order matter for future sequential reading?

Tags: python, performance, io, storage

I'm preprocessing a large volume of raw files for future analysis where they'll be read back sequentially. The raw files are on a network file server and the the processed files are being written to a local external USB drive (12TB HDD, ReFS w/ 4k clusters). Processed files are ~100 KB each and I anticipate accessing them all a few times per year sorted by filename. There are 60+ million files.....

**My general question pertains to how important is it that the preprocessed files are written in the same order they'll be read?**  Details follow...

Python's multiprocessing module is being used for the preprocessing to max out I/O and CPU. I have a loop within os.walk that lists N=1000 files from the fileserver, then passes that list into Pool.map(), which maps the work to a function that processes the files one by one and writes them to the USB drive. This seems to be working well from a performance standpoint. However I've noticed that the files are not being processed and written in perfect sequential order, which I assume is because the pools are uncoordinated. It's fairly close but not exact. Here's a fictional sample (pretend these are filenames) listed in the order they're written to the USB drive:

1
4
2
3
6
5
9
11
7
10
8
12
17
21

In the future I'll be reading these back in small batches of "adjacent filenames" (N = 16 or 32) like this:
(1,2, 3,...14,15,16). All files will be read sequentially but they're processed in batches (feeding them into a neural network). I assume this reading will be single-treaded so it's actually requesting one file at a time from the OS, although I may end up relying on a data-loader in TensorFlow or PyTorch, which could do multiple reads in parallel....I'm still learning about that part and am not sure how it will work exactly. But gist of it is that the files will e read sequentially based on their filename.

**My questions are:**

1. **How important is it that the files be written in the exact same order they'll be read?** Am I causing excessive disk thrashing even though the files are written in *approximate* filename order such that most files within a given "read-batch" are "close together" on the disk platters?  I'm worried about decreased performance and increased risk of drive failure.
2. **If I do want to address this, how would I do so?**  My untested noob ideas are below:

   1. Have the pool return the processed files as in-memory objects, and then use single-treaded code to write them to disk. This would consume more memory forcing me to decrease the number and/or depth of the pools, leading to greater overhead. (I assume the single-threaded writing would not become a bottleneck)

      1. Perhaps this single-threaded write activity could be parallelized next to the os.walk? They're hitting different I/O channels and neither is CPU intensive.
   2. My second thought was to somehow coordinate the pools to get them to write files in sequential order, but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible or desirable.
   3. Third idea is to have the pools write files to the system's SSD instead of the USB drive, then at some regular interval use single-treaded code to move them to the external USB drive in the desired order. Essentially treating the SSD like a large buffer.

Anyways, if anyone has any thoughts on how to approach this, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Unclear why order really matters here. Ultimately, depending on the data, I suggest using a database, rather than raw file parsing. Alternatively, can you not gzip the smaller files into larger batches to reduce io?

Comment: I don't know how much the order matters, but it seems like it would?  The files are essentially individual video frames stored as jpeg files (beside the point) which need to be read sequentially for analysis. I'll be using TensorFlow or PyTorch to analyze them, and those libraries accept small batches of images.  Gzip is a great idea, I will look into that. It would add some overhead and reduce flexability when later analyzing the data, but perhaps worth the tradeoffs.